# How to cycle through all the checkboxes and nothing else in a Java container

Tags: java, user-interface, jcheckbox

I'd like to be able to do in Java what the pseudo code below suggests:

```
for each jcheckbox in gui.panel1
  jcheckbox.setEnabled(true);
next
```

I don't want to enable every component; just the checkboxes.

Comment: Use `instanceof` to check for `JCheckBox`.

Comment: I was asking a question that I knew the answer to, as suggested by SO.

Comment: Whichever one of you highandmighties downvoted me, I suggest you read this [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and scroll through it. "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." Frankly, though, I couldn't care less about downvotes. And if it was because the question-and-answer weren't worth asking-and-answering, show me the criteria. It is certainly not an obvious solution.

Comment: @Patterned: Please note that the checkboxes ARE, after the fact, IN an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void enableCheckboxes(){
    Component [] c = gui.panel.getComponents();
    for (Component c1 : c) {
      if (c1 instanceof JCheckBox) {
        c1.setEnabled(true);
      }
    }
  }
```

I'd wondered when I'd use the `instanceof` operator. I kept seeing it lots of places. And I was unaware of the power of `getComponents()`. Makes me want to tackle `Reflection` soon.

Thanks to Niemeyer's *Learning Java*, chapter 17--Using Swing Components.

If there's another way--and surely there is--I hope to see it soon.